# how to compare first table id and second table category id and display data category_id wise database in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have create two table like this

** i have click Freedom Fighters only Mahatma Gandhi then i have click Sports Person only show Sania Mirza**

```
category:ID | NAME
people:ID|NAME|CATEGORY_ID
```

My first table data

```
"1" "Freedom Fighters"
"2" "Sports Person"
"3" "Scientist"
"4" "Politicians"
"5" "Celebrities"
```

My second table data

```
 NAME               category_id
"Mahatma Gandhi"    "1"
"Sania Mirza"       "2"
"C. V. Raman"       "3"
"Swami Vivekananda" "4"
```

**My query is **

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from people where category_id = (select id from category)", null);
```

But only show the first row of thesecond table

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from people where category_id in (select id from category)
```

in this query you get you need......

Comment: ya but in this case show all data in people i have click first Freedom Fighters then show Mahatma Gandhi any solution for this?

Comment: just pass category_id ="Mahatma Gandhi " id ...

select * from people where category_id ="id".